# The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file that contains its element like

```
<ab:test>Str</ab:test>
```

When I am trying to access it using the code:

```
XElement tempElement = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("ab:test")).FirstOrDefault();
```

It's giving me this error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

How should I access it?

Comment: You certainly have a way to handle namespaces so you don't have to (or in this case, you can't) put them in the name. You should look into this direction.

Comment: Not only does the XML specification say that ":" is [allowed for names](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) (and to start names!), but the [Get method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357369.aspx) of XName doesn't document that it throws XmlException!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324960/creating-xdocument-with-xsischemalocation-namespace for correct namespace handling.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

If you want to use namespaces, LINQ to XML makes that really easy:

```
XNamespace ab = "http://whatever-the-url-is";
XElement tempElement = doc.Descendants(ab + "test").FirstOrDefault();
```

Look for an `xmlns:ab=...` section in your document to find out which namespace URI "ab" refers to.

Comment: It works, but the problem is that value of xmlns:ab is generated dynamically based on time stamp. How can i get its value?

Comment: @coure06: The namespace URI is dynamic? That's pretty weird. But yes, you can get it by finding the attribute value for `XNamespace.Xmlns + "ab"` from whichever element declares it.

Comment: I am getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839628/how-to-get-certain-elements-inside-an-xml-document/42840373#42840373

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't seem to work with the newer string templating syntax, so `$"{ab}test"` gives the same error

Comment: @Liam: I'd expect that - `ab + "test"` isn't performing string concatenation; it's using the `+(XNamespace, string)` operator to create an `XName`.

Answer (score 27):

Try putting your namespace in `{` ... `}` like so:

```
string xfaNamespace = "{http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/2.6/}";
```

Comment: why should you use curly braces?  What is the benefit?

Comment: Using the `XNamespace` method essentially just does this for you. `.ToString` on a `XNamespace` obviously just formats the string correctly for you. So this is the same tnhing done a different way, there is no benefit in either

Answer (score 22):

I was having the same error.  I found I was adding code...

```
var ab = "http://whatever-the-url-is";
```

... but ab was determined to be a string.  This caused the error reported by OP.  Instead of using the VAR keyword, I used the actual data type XNamespace...

```
XNamespace ab = "http://whatever-the-url-is";
```

... and the problem went away.

Answer (score 7):

There is an overload of the Get method you might want to try that takes into account the namespace. Try this:

```
XElement tempElement = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("test", "ab")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `ab` isn't the actual namespace here though - it's just the alias for the namespace. (I don't know the right terminology unfortunately.) LINQ to XML makes this easy with `XNamespace`. It's rare that you need to explicitly call `XName.Get` in LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 5):

Try to get namespace from the document

```
var ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `AndroidManifest.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml.DISABLED` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The ':' character is problematic when it is contained in namespace. Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <SAMLConfiguration xmlns="urn:componentspace:SAML:2.0:configuration">
    <ServiceProvider Name="http://avanteam"
      Description="Avanteam Service Provider"
      AssertionConsumerServiceUrl="SAML/AssertionConsumerService"
      LocalCertificateFile="Certificates\sp.pfx"
      LocalCertificatePassword="password"/>
  </SAMLConfiguration>
```

A solution that works in all cases is to use the `GetName` method on an instance of `XNamespace`. Example with default namespace:

```
var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var serviceProviderNode = doc.Element(ns.GetName("SAMLConfiguration"))?.Element(ns.GetName("ServiceProvider"));
```