# The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a Attribute name

Tags: linq-to-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The ‘:’ character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575546/the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x3a-cannot-be-included-in-a-name)

I get that error when i use LinQ to XML .It's clear the error is due to reading XML and not linQ.

Xml used:

```
<Worksheet ss:Name="Location" ss:Protected="1">
```

I'm facing problem reading the Attribute value "ss:Name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use provided support of namespaces in LINQ to XML. Look for [XNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx) class.