# Use the ':' (0x3A) character in a Regex sentence?

Tags: c#, regex, syntax-highlighting

No, this is not a replicate of [The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2575546/773879)

I have a Regex for my syntax highlighter for my scripting language:

```
`@"\bClass+(?<range>\w+?)\b"`
```

which basically marks Class **Name**

(with the engine I got online)

I'm no master in Regex but for some reason the `:` character that uses my language to create labels - doesn't work.

I tried

```
 @"\b:+(?<range>\w+?)\b"`, `@"\b\:+(?<range>\w+?)\b"`<RB> `@"\b(\x3A)+(?<range>\w+?)\b"
```

And it refuses to work!

Any ideas?

Comment: [This is a great tool to test out RegEx sequences on-the-fly.](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) I use it all the time. Perhaps it'll help you solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue in your case is not the `:` itself, but the `\b` before it. `\b` marks the boundary between a word character and nonword character, but while `Class` is comprised of word characters, `:` is a nonword character.  So `\b` is behaving differently for `:` than it would for `Class`, so:

```
`\bClass` matches " Class Name"
`\b:` does not match " : Name"
```

If you use your original expression but replace the first `\b` with `(?<!\w)`, it may identify the `:` properly.