# Regex unicode and accent

Tags: python, regex

Why `(^|\b)на́($|\b)` doesn't match `віч на́ віч`?

`re.sub(r'(^|\b)на́($|\b)', 'на', 'віч на́ віч', flags=re.UNICODE)` is giving `'віч на́ віч'`, while I want `віч на віч`.

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the problem. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Try \s instead of \b

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton A [mcve].

Comment: @Tomalak but it _is_ - there is literally no more information that is needed

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels Not a good solution. I'm pretty sure things like `віч (на́) віч` should match as well.

Comment: @Tomalak it is minimal, complete, and verifiable. I was able to reproduce his problem on regexr.com

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels Since the meaning of `\b` varies by regex flag, a three-liner that shows how the OP is executing the regex is better than a naked regex.

Comment: `\b` checks against `a-zA-Z0-9_` (unless `u` modifier is used), but even then can be finicky. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590098/javascript-regexp-word-boundaries-unicode-characters) for more information

Comment: I believe the issue is the characters:

    на́

are both in fact word boundaries.  See how this works:

    import re

    text = "## "
  
    if re.search(r"##\b", text):
        print ("it will not get here")
    else:
        print ("see?")

Comment: @sniperd technically, yes, but that's only because `\b` checks against ASCII characters in *most* flavours of regex. I believe Java does this right (works with Unicode), but I can't say for other languages

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels you can use this `(?:^|(?<=\W))на́(?=\W|$)`

Comment: @ctwheels Same regex is `(?<!\w)на́(?!\w)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep you're right that's much better too.

Comment: @ctwheels The question must be reopened or the close reason must be changed. Do you know any good thread where the `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)` boundaries are dwelt upon?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not specifically, the closest I could find was [difference between \w and \b regular expression meta characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters), which doesn't cover them being used in the way expressed in the comments above. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880566/3600709), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215293/3600709), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295621/3600709) also suggest it (esp. latter). [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com/advanced.php) to search the web for symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\W`:

```
import re
s = "віч на́ віч"
final_s = re.findall('\W+', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
"віч на́ віч"
```