# "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name"

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, infopath

I have a code which will read some xml file(s). I tried different ways to solve this problem, but couldn't. Also I tried to code like this:

```
Namespace my = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-01-11T08:31:30";                
XElement myEgitimBilgileri = XDocument.Load(@"C:\25036077.xml").Element("my:"+ "Egitim_Bilgileri");
```

But all the time the same mistake. Here is the original:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                               
    XElement myEgitimBilgileri =    
    XDocument.Load(@"C:\25036077.xml").Element("my:Egitim_Bilgileri");

    if (myEgitimBilgileri != null)
    {
        foreach (XElement element in myEgitimBilgileri.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\tValue: {1}", element.Name, element.Value.Trim());
        }
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Here is a path of my xml file:

```
<my:Egitim_Bilgileri>
        <my:egitimler_sap>
            <my:sap_eduname></my:sap_eduname>
            <my:sap_edufaculty></my:sap_edufaculty>
            <my:sap_eduprofession></my:sap_eduprofession>
            <my:sap_diplomno></my:sap_diplomno>
            <my:sap_edulevel></my:sap_edulevel>
            <my:sap_edustartdate xsi:nil="true"></my:sap_edustartdate>
            <my:sap_eduenddate xsi:nil="true"></my:sap_eduenddate>
        </my:egitimler_sap>
    </my:Egitim_Bilgileri>
```

and this is the path of my namespace in XML

```
xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-01-11T08:31:30"

xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2008-01-23T00:43:17"
```

Comment: See also [The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575546/the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x3a-cannot-be-included-in-a-name).

Answer (score 14):

The code `Element("my:" + "Egitim_Bilgileri")` is the same as `Element("my:Egitim_Bilgileri")` which is taken to mean the element *named* "my:Egitim_Bilgileri" *in the default namespace* (there is an [implicit conversion from string to XName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit.aspx)).

However, `:` *is invalid* in an element name (outside of the namespace separation) and thus will result in a run-time exception.

Instead, the code should be `Element(my + "Egitim_Bilgileri")` where `my` is an [XNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx) object. The XNamespace object's `+` operator, when given a string as the second operand, results in an [XName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) object that can then be used with the [`Element(XName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) method.

For instance:

```
XNamespace my = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-01-11T08:31:30";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\25036077.xml");
// The following variable/assignment can be omitted,
// it is to show the + operator of XNamespace and how it results in XName
XName nodeName = my + "Egitim_Bilgileri";
XElement myEgitimBilgileri = doc.Element(nodeName);
```

Happy coding... and condolences for having to deal with InfoPath :)

---

I prefer to use XPath in most cases. Among other things it allows easily selecting nested nodes and avoids having to "check for null" each level as may be required with `node.Element(x).Element(y)` constructs.

```
using System.Xml.XPath; // for XPathSelectElement extension method
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
ns.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-01-11T08:31:30")
// Note that there is no XName object. Instead the XPath string is parsed
// and namespace resolution happens via the XmlNamespaceManager
XElement myEgitimBilgileri = doc.XPathSelectElement("/my:myFields/my:Egitim_Bilgileri", ns);
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, but now the program doesn't see the element I need. I mean that if (myEgitimBilgileri != null)  is null.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use Elemets(). Can you help to run this code?

Comment: @Abdulyar Verify the namespace is correct and they are correctly specified in the XML. There are two namespaces mentioned in the post. (I suspect that the XML fragment shown is *not* the Root Element of the document...? `Element/Elements` only looks at direct children. Consider `XPathSelectElements` for more advanced queries.)

Comment: If you don't mind,can have a talk with you in online messenger?

Comment: @Abdulyar Prefer not, sorry. Feel free up update the post with any relevant information (full XML, for instance) and I can update my answer from there. If that is indeed the root element, it looks like there is a `xmlns:my=....` missing on it.

Comment: Ok, <my:Egitim_Bilgileri> is not root. The root is <my:myfield>. I cheked it, and it works, but how can call the <my:Egitim_Bilgileri> if it is not root?

Comment: @Abdulyar I updated my answer with an XPath example. More examples and documetation can be found online.

Comment: Sorry for my foolishness, but the program doesn't show the result in console. How we can write it to a new file?

Comment: @Abdulyar I have answered the questions in the post. Consider adding a new question with the new problem/issues so that they can be addressed.