# using ':' character in XDocument for Excel generation - C#

Tags: excel, linq-to-xml

I'm pretty new to the programming world, so this question might be silly, but I'm stuck, and was hoping to get some help.

I'm using XDocument to alter and add information to an Excel worksheet (which is an XML-document), in a project to get an Excel report out of Autodesk Revit.
The worksheet document consists of worksheet information including rows and cells in this configuration:

```
<row r="11" spans="1:11" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
    <c r="A11" s="198" t="inlineStr">
        <is>
            <t>example</t>
        </is>
    </c>
    <c r="B11" s="199" t="inlineStr">
        <is>
            <t>string</t>
        </is>
    </c>
    <c r="C11" s="200"/>
    <c r="D11" s="201"/>
    <c r="E11" s="201"/>
    <c r="F11" s="202"/>
    <c r="G11" s="203"/>
    <c r="H11" s="204"/>
    <c r="I11" s="205"/>
    <c r="J11" s="205"/>
    <c r="K11" s="206"/>
</row>
```

The relevant part of the code is in the row-element. The spans-attribute has a value of "1:11", and that's where my problem is. It won't let me input a ':' character as the attribute's value. I've searched the net, and found that it has something to do with the namespace-declaration at this link:
["The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213251/the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x3a-cannot-be-included-in-a-name)

However, getting this ':' character into the attribute value is imperative to the workings of the Excel document. I create the row element as follows:

```
XElement row = new XElement("row",
                    new XAttribute("r", i.ToString()),
                    new XAttribute("spans", "1:" + collumnCount.ToString()),
                    new XAttribute("x14ac:dyDescent", "0.2"));
```

I don't understand why it doesn't let me put a ':' into the value of the XAttribute, as this is just a string. Is there any way to make this work?

I've tried adding the string "1:11" to an XMLAttribute, using an XMLDocument. This does work, but I can't believe it's not possible with XDocument.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not the **attribute value** of `spans` that's giving you this error, it's the **attribute name** `x14ac:dyDescent`. You're about to enter the wonderful world of xml namespaces... good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You should include <kbd>:</kbd> in your element names. It's now allowed. If you see someone do that, that <kbd>:</kbd> is not part of the element name, it's the separator between the namespace and the element name. So in order to get the following XML file:

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://m.xyz.com/rss/" version="2.0">
    <channel vendor="ABC" lastpublishdate="05/12/2013 01:02"/>
    <title>Videos</title>
    <media:thumbnail width="180" height="75" />
</rss>
```

You have to write something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = "55";

            XNamespace aw = "http://m.xyz.com/rss/";
            XDocument document = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), 
                new XElement(
                    "rss", 
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "media", "http://m.xyz.com/rss/"), 
                    new XAttribute("version", "2.0"),

                    new XElement("channel",
                        new XAttribute("vendor", "ABC"),
                        new XAttribute("lastpublishdate", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"))),

                        new XElement("title", "Videos"),
                        new XElement(
                            aw + "thumbnail", 
                            new XAttribute("width", x.Trim()), 
                            new XAttribute("height", x.Trim())
                        )
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```