# Creating XDocument with xsi:schemaLocation namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xnamespace

I need to create the following XML and I'm trying to do this using XDocument. However, I'm having trouble specifying the name spaces.

```
<AssessmentOrderRequest
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15 http://ns.hr-xml.org/2_5/HR-XML-2_5/StandAlone/AssessmentOrderRequest.xsd"
    xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</AssessmentOrderRequest>
```

This is the sort of code that I'm looking for, however, I can't create attributes with a colon in the name for the `xsi:schemaLocation`.

```
return new XDocument(
    new XElement("AssessmentOrderRequest",
        new XAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", XNamespace.Get("http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15 http://ns.hr-xml.org/2_5/HR-XML-2_5/StandAlone/AssessmentOrderRequest.xsd")),
        new XAttribute("xmlns", XNamespace.Get("http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15")),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"))
    )
);
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is because the `xsi` is a namespace in itself. You would need to do something like:

```
        XNamespace xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15");
        XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        XNamespace schemaLocation = XNamespace.Get("http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15 http://ns.hr-xml.org/2_5/HR-XML-2_5/StandAlone/AssessmentOrderRequest.xsd");

        return new XDocument(
            new XElement(xmlns + "AssessmentOrderRequest",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
                new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation)
            )
        );
```

EDIT: Updated with final code that I used to solve the problem. With thanks to the original answer from James.

Comment: With that code I get the following error when accessing the ToString() of the XDocument. The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15' within the same start element tag.

Comment: James: I edited your answer to what I actually used thanks to the answer you gave. Thanks.

Comment: @James Thank you so much for sharing this working code. I was pulling my hair trying to get the namespaces to work.