# Unable to Create New XDocument with namespace from scratch

Tags: c#, xml, idml

We are trying to create a new XML document with the below content using XDocument without querying an existing one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<idPkg:Story xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="8.0">
    <Story Self="xyz">  
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/$ID/NormalParagraphStyle">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                  <Content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut ipsum et libero aliquam venenatis. Vestibulum molestie neque id leo sodales porta. Proin ullamcorper molestie mi a commodo. Aenean mattis tincidunt purus id sagittis. Nam bibendum metus est, id condimentum nisi tristique posuere. Sed interdum sollicitudin tincidunt. Fusce volutpat neque turpis, eget porttitor mauris ultricies quis. Morbi posuere ligula lobortis orci dictum lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut ipsum et libero aliquam venenatis. Vestibulum molestie neque id leo sodales porta. Proin ullamcorper molestie mi a commodo. Aenean mattis tincidunt purus id sagittis. Nam bibendum metus est, id condimentum nisi tristique posuere. Sed interdum sollicitudin tincidunt. Fusce volutpat neque turpis, eget porttitor mauris ultricies quis. Morbi posuere ligula lobortis orci dictum lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut ipsum et libero aliquam venenatis. Vestibulum molestie neque id leo sodales porta. Proin ullamcorper molestie mi a commodo. Aenean mattis tincidunt purus id sagittis. Nam bibendum metus est, id condimentum nisi tristique posuere. Sed interdum sollicitudin tincidunt. Fusce volutpat neque turpis, eget porttitor mauris ultricies quis. Morbi posuere ligula lobortis orci dictum lobortis.</Content>
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
    </Story>
</idPkg:Story>
```

We have tried the following code:

```
        Xdocument = new XDocument
        {
            Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
        };
        XNamespace schemaLocation = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes");
        XNamespace idPkg = "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging";

        Xdocument.Add(new XElement(idPkg + "Story",
            new XAttribute("xmlns" + "idPkg", "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging"),
            new XAttribute("DOMVersion", "8.0")),
                    new XElement(idPkg + "Story"), 
                    new XAttribute("Self", "xyz" + EnumHelper.GetDescription(section)));
```

When we run the method, it errors on `new XElement(idPkg + "Story"),` and we get the following error message: `This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.`

We looked at the following question: 
[Creating XDocument with xsi:schemaLocation namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324960/creating-xdocument-with-xsischemalocation-namespace)

Comment: possible duplicate of [XDocument containing namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998710/xdocument-containing-namespaces)

Comment: @ErikPhilips We aren't querying the XDocument, we are creating a new one from scratch.

Comment: XML allows only single root element.

Comment: @PetSerAl, sorry forgot to include all of the XML we desire to create from scratch. It now has a single root. Notice the </idPkg:Story> tail end is closed now.

Comment: But your code still add one `XElement` after another, not inside.

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes thats the answer, we had the parentheses in the wrong place next to XAttribute, which should be a comma. `new XAttribute("DOMVersion", "8.0"),` You can answer it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code try to add second element to `XDocument`, that violate XML specification and produce exception. I personally prefer to write XML creation code as single statement with indentation, that resemble XML structure:

```
XNamespace idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging";
XDocument document=new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8","yes"),
    new XElement(idPkg+"Story",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"idPkg",idPkg),
        new XAttribute("DOMVersion","8.0"),
        new XElement("Story",
            new XAttribute("Self","zxc"),
            new XElement("ParagraphStyleRange",
                new XAttribute("AppliedParagraphStyle","ParagraphStyle/$ID/NormalParagraphStyle"),
                new XElement("CharacterStyleRange",
                    new XAttribute("AppliedCharacterStyle","CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]"),
                    new XElement("Content","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut ipsum et libero aliquam venenatis. Vestibulum molestie neque id leo sodales porta. Proin ullamcorper molestie mi a commodo. Aenean mattis tincidunt purus id sagittis. Nam bibendum metus est, id condimentum nisi tristique posuere. Sed interdum sollicitudin tincidunt. Fusce volutpat neque turpis, eget porttitor mauris ultricies quis. Morbi posuere ligula lobortis orci dictum lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut ipsum et libero aliquam venenatis. Vestibulum molestie neque id leo sodales porta. Proin ullamcorper molestie mi a commodo. Aenean mattis tincidunt purus id sagittis. Nam bibendum metus est, id condimentum nisi tristique posuere. Sed interdum sollicitudin tincidunt. Fusce volutpat neque turpis, eget porttitor mauris ultricies quis. Morbi posuere ligula lobortis orci dictum lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut ipsum et libero aliquam venenatis. Vestibulum molestie neque id leo sodales porta. Proin ullamcorper molestie mi a commodo. Aenean mattis tincidunt purus id sagittis. Nam bibendum metus est, id condimentum nisi tristique posuere. Sed interdum sollicitudin tincidunt. Fusce volutpat neque turpis, eget porttitor mauris ultricies quis. Morbi posuere ligula lobortis orci dictum lobortis.")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Also you should use `XNamespace.Xmlns+"idPkg"` instead of `"xmlns"+"idPkg"`.