# Parsing Complex XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have [CDA XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_Document_Architecture) I am trying to parse and query it using LINQ. However, I am unable to retrieve the values.

I am trying the following LINQ code:

```
var cdafile = XDocument.Load("cda.xml");

var patientCity = from c in cdafile.Elements("recordTarget")
                                   .Elements("patientRole")
                                   .Elements("addr")
                  select (string)c.Element("city").Value;
```

I am getting empty value in `patientCity`. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://xreg2.nist.gov:8080/hitspValidation/schema/cdar2c32/infrastructure/cda/C32_CDA.xsd">
  <realmCode code="US"/>
  <title>Cypress C32 Patient Test Record: Nelson Tuff</title>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <id root="Cypress" extension="4fe1ecbca9ffcc03cd0004e3"/>
      <addr use="HP">
        <streetAddressLine>202 Burlington Rd.</streetAddressLine>
        <city>Bedford</city>
        <state>MA</state>
        <postalCode>01730</postalCode>
      </addr>
      <telecom value="tel:+1-781-271-3000"/>
      <patient>
        <name>
          <given>George</given>
          <family>Mathew</family>
        </name>
      </patient>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Linq to Xml with Xml namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340411/use-linq-to-xml-with-xml-namespaces) (plus related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575546/the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x3a-cannot-be-included-in-a-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include default namespace in your query (`urn:hl7-org:v3`) and query `Root` property of `XDocument`:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
var patientCity = 
    from c in cdafile.Root
        .Elements(ns + "recordTarget")
        .Elements(ns + "patientRole")
        .Elements(ns + "addr") 
    select (string)c.Element(ns + "city").Value;
```

This is because `Elements` searches *direct children* of node (which in case of `XDocument` would be document itself with its only direct children of `ClinicalDocument`).

You can use `Descendants` to search *any* descendants of current node, ignoring hierarchical walking altogether:

```
var patientCity = from c in cdafile.Descendants(ns + "city") select c.Value;
```