# How do I get these attributes?

Tags: c#, xml

So I'm trying to retrieve some values from attributes in an XML element but have trouble with the ':'.

```
<Vehicle xmlns:qs="urn:quote-sys-private-data" qs:Make="ALFA ROMEO" qs:Body="Convertible" qs:NumberOfDoors="2" qs:Fuel="Petrol" qs:TransmissionType="Manual">
```

I need to get the Make, Body, NumberOfDoors, Fuel and TransmissionType.

Error I get when trying to do the following:

```
vehicleNode.Element("Vehicle_Model").Attribute("Val").Value,
```

is,

`The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name`

vehicleNode is an XElement.

To my knowledge, this is not the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575546/the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x3a-cannot-be-included-in-a-name/2575563#2575563) as this has the `<ab:test>` as an element and not an attribute on an element.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: A similar error has a fix here [The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575563/6741868)

Comment: @PatrickHofman - you've marked it as an incorrect duplicate

Comment: @PatrickHofman - my apologies, I misread the duplicate - you are right. I will slink away now.

Comment: @MattJones No problem

Comment: You could try `vehicleNode.Element("Vehicle_Model").Attribute(XName.Get("Val", "urn:quote-sys-private-data")).Value,`