# SpreadsheetLight Updating excel file

Tags: c#, spreadsheetlight

I would like to read the excel file then find the correct row and add a value to that row But I am getting a error message file is used by another process.

> I have add the file to the FileStream so I am not sure why I am getting this error?

System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'D:\repos\FHIRVal\Update.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.'

```
public static int UpdateExecelFile(string id, string status)
    {
        string FilePath = "D:\\repos\\FHIRVal\\Update.xlsx";


        using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument())
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open);
            SLDocument sheet = new SLDocument(fs, "Sheet");

            SLWorksheetStatistics stats = sheet.GetWorksheetStatistics();
            for (int j = 1; j < stats.EndRowIndex; j++)
            {
                var value = sheet.GetCellValueAsString(j, 2);

                if (value == id)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} --- {1}", "Updating File", id));
                    string updateRow = string.Format("{0}{1}", "C",j);

                    sl.SetCellValue(updateRow, status);
                }

            }
            sheet.SaveAs(FilePath);
            fs.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575546/the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x3a-cannot-be-included-in-a-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being)

Comment: I googled your error message and I found SO answer right away. I think it's fair to say it's something you should have done yourself too before asking a new question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the order incorrect I needed to have the fs.close before the sheetsaveas .

Comment: This error was not posted in the original post of the question