# Renaming XDocument Element Names

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am having trouble renaming XML element names. I'm attempting to achieve the following.

> Input:

```
<Addresses>
    <AddressItem>
        <AddressLine1>RZN850PXKYG</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2>RYK57IT7Y9Z</AddressLine2>
        <AddressType>Physical</AddressType>
        <City>Some City</City>
        <PostalCode>9999</PostalCode>
        <Province>Some Province</Province>
        <Suburb>Some Suburb</Suburb>
    </AddressItem>
</Addresses>
```

> Expected output:

```
<b:Addresses>
    <b:AddressItem>
        <b:AddressLine1>RZN850PXKYG</b:AddressLine1>
        <b:AddressLine2>RYK57IT7Y9Z</b:AddressLine1>
        <b:AddressType>Physical</b:AddressType>
        <b:City>Some City</b:City>
        <b:PostalCode>9999</b:PostalCode>
        <b:Province>Some Province</b:Province>
        <b:Suburb>Some Suburb</b:Suburb>
    </b:AddressItem>
</b:Addresses>
```

Previously I have successfully added attributes and renamed elements using something similar to this:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(requestObj);

foreach (var element in xmlDoc.Descendants())
{
    if (element.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("something"))
    {
        //example rename element
        element.Name = "request";

        XNamespace b = "http://schemas.something.org/bla/07/WebServices.Stuff";
        XNamespace i = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

        //set it's attributes
        element.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xmlns + "b", b);
        element.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xmlns + "i", i);
    }
}
```

I have attempted to achieve my expected result by simply using the below code but the colon is giving me problems it seems:

```
foreach (var element in xmlDoc.Descendants())
{
    element.Name = "b:" + element.Name;
}
```

I have searched using the error message received (`System.Xml.XmlException: 'The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.'`) but none of the solutions seems applicable to elements needing to be renamed recursively.

Comment: Did you try and google your error message?  I just copied your error and pasted it in Google.  This was the first thing that came up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575546/the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x3a-cannot-be-included-in-a-name

Comment: You cannot have an element `<b:Addresses>` without a namespace declaration corresponding to `b`, such as `xmlns:b="https://whatever-you-want-here"`.  Without a namespace declaration your XML is not well formed.  What namespace do you want?  Is it `"http://schemas.something.org/bla/07/WebServices.Stuff"`?

Comment: @dbc yes I'm adding the name space deceleration to the xml in a seperate process at the moment and then attempting to change the elements manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `<Addresses>` is some nested element in your XML document, and some upper-level node shall declare a namespace `xmlns:b="http://schemas.something.org/bla/07/WebServices.Stuff"`, you can modify your XML as follows:

```
XNamespace newNamespace = "http://schemas.something.org/bla/07/WebServices.Stuff";

// Move Addresses elements and children into the new namespace
foreach (var e in xmlDoc.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Addresses").SelectMany(a => a.DescendantsAndSelf()))
{
    e.Name = newNamespace + e.Name.LocalName;
}

// Optionally assign the namespace prefix "b" to some container element in scope.
xmlDoc.Root.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xmlns + "b", newNamespace.NamespaceName);
```

Notes:

1. You are trying to modify the [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.name?view=netframework-4.8) property of selected [`XElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.8) objects to be `"b:"+element.Name;`, however `XElement.Name` is not a `string`, it is an [`XName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xname?view=netframework-4.8), which encapsulates an XML namespace and local name -- not an XML namespace *prefix* and local name.  Thus attempting to assign `Name` to have a specific prefix fails, and throws an exception.

   In LINQ-to-XML, `XElement` objects do not know their namespace *prefix*.  They know their *actual namespace*.  Only while outputting an `XElement` to an XML string will `XmlWriter` attempt to determine a namespace prefix by looking for an [xmlns declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181888//3744182) in scope -- or if none is in scope then it will emit an appropriate `xmlns` declaration automatically on the current element.

   Thus, to modify an element to look like `<b:Addresses>`, you must modify its *actual namespace* to be whatever `b:` should correspond to.  Now, you may not care about the precise prefix chosen, but if you do, you can subsequently specify one on some appropriate element in scope, for instance the root element.

   Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZQtWNO).
2. If you don't care about the specific prefix used, you can entirely omit the `// Optionally` code and .Net's `XmlWriter` will add namespace declarations for you automatically.

   Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5bCQtd).

Comment: thank you very much for you in depth explanation and examples, I will be testing all of this now and mark this as the correct answer if I have no further questions.