# Cannot read Attribute value LINQ XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

This is XML structure:

```
<items>
        <item>
            <title>Weź udział w grze historycznej</title>
            <link>https://legionowo.pl/a/wez-udzial-w-grze-historycznej</link>
            <description><![CDATA[<img src="https://legionowo.pl/img/artykuly/4/2022_07/x41594.jpg.pagespeed.ic.9BJkaqvzdK.jpg%22%3E<br><br>]]></description>
            <pubDate>Fri, 01 Jul 2022 09:10:50 +0000</pubDate>
            <media:content url="https://legionowo.pl/img/artykuly/4/2022_07/x41594.jpg.pagespeed.ic.9BJkaqvzdK.jpg" medium="image" />
            <guid isPermaLink="false">https://legionowo.pl/a/wez-udzial-w-grze-historycznej</guid>
        </item>
<items>
```

this is C# method:

```
private async Task _XElementGet()
        {
            XElement doc = XElement.Load("C:\\mail.xml");
            List<XElement> list;
            list = (from prod in doc.Elements("item")
                    select prod).ToList();
            foreach(XElement item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
```

and its empty, but when i am trying to use XDocument it works and it looks:

```
private async Task _XDocumentGet()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\mail.xml");
            List<XElement> list;
            list = (from prod in doc.Descendants("item")
                    select prod).ToList();
            foreach(XElement item in list)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(item.Element("title"));
                Console.WriteLine(item.FirstAttribute.Value);
            }
        }
```

This is first.

Second is about this Attribute "media:content" -> i cannot get its value because i get this error message:

**System.Xml.XmlException: 'The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.' how to read value from this attribute**

Any ideas how i can fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575546/the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x3a-cannot-be-included-in-a-name)

Comment: Please one one question at a time

Comment: @MarkusMeyer nope

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement description = doc.Descendants("description").FirstOrDefault();
            string descr = (string)description;
            string descrDecoded = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(descr);
 
 
        }

    }
 


}
```

Comment: this doesnt works.

Comment: What you posted does not have a colon (0x3a).  You must be reading something different than the posted code.

Comment: try read this: <media:content />

Comment: Your posted code doesn't have the Namespace "media" defined.  I assumed you only posted a portion of your XML file.  Media must be defined earlier in the xml data than what is posted.